# Import problem: What is the importance of the table 'importexport_importdata', can i truncate it and what is it good for anyhow?

Tags: database, import, magento-1.6, export

i have a problem with a clients Magento DB while trying to replicate it on my computer.

Needless to say that i was not able to export the DB via the Magento Backend (using **1.6** Community version), that crashed the customers page somehow blocking some DB tables (never figured out what exactly happened, gave me *1205 errors* on the *log_visitor* table when trying to login, but after some DB maintenance it worked again). So i finally managed to export the whole db with the great [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/en/) script (in chunks, exporting the logs and product tables separately).

So the current situation:

**Export** via Adminer works like a charm.

**Import** gives me an error while trying to import the mentioned 'importexport_importdata' table which only has one entry but with a size of ~2.5 MB ! So while i was able to work around the huge size of the clients log and product tables (between ~250k and ~800k entries) by exporting them separatedly, i just can't import that table because its only entry is simply to big to import in one chunk.

I could cut the import of this entry to smaller pieces and simply append them to the entry, but i read on one page that this table could be truncated which i would prefer todo. The problem is that i haven't found much information about this table at all and am reluctant to truncate it without having more information about it.

**QUESTION** is it really save to truncate this table and what purpose does the data stored in it serve?

Comment: Have you tried to truncate it locally and then import? As it won't affect your customers (which are stored in `customer_XXX` tables), I believe it is just a temporary table for imports via admin.

Comment: Thanks Julien, yes, i have truncated it locally, but as all the 'testing' i can do locally is only 'testing' and probably doesn't reflect the real life activities they have on their page, i'd feel a lot more comfortable knowing WHAT exactly is stored in this table (they don't have a test system). I found close to no real info on that in the nets, so it'd be good to have this thread here to clarify its function and importance in more detail with reliable information.

Comment: Let's hope some guys like Marius step by and give us a hint ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I my opinion it is safe to truncate this table as even the magento db backup system ignores it. See [`Mage_Backup_Model_Db`](http://doc4dev.net/doc/Magento/1/class-Mage_Backup_Model_Db.html) as it has a list of data tables to ignore that the import data table is the only one in this.

```
protected $_ignoreDataTablesList = array(
    'importexport/importdata'
);
```

I would test this locally and as always make sure you have a full database backup (not via magento) before doing anything like this in the database.

Comment: Nice, thank you, the fact that the internal Backup disregards it is the kind of proof i was looking for :)